# Is there any way we can specify the TCP Options in client

Tags: curl, tcp

I am testing the tcp options parameters from a client request. Basically I am using curl to send requests. So is there any way I can manually specify the TCP options for my client so that I can test the same in my Device Under Test or any other tools to manipulate the TCP options header in the TCP Packet ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool which is written in python that can graft the packet however you need. The tool is called "Scapy". Using this tool, I achieved my requirement.

Thanks!